# ES6 template literals just output my expressions as strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm checking out the node.js Hapi framework, and the tutorial I'm following is ES6.  I've read that node supports all the standardized bits os ES2015 out the box, so I assumed this would work :

```
 server.start(() => console.log('Started At: ${server.info.uri}'));
```

but no dice., I keep getting :

```
 [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
  Started At: ${server.info.uri}
```

Where am I going wrong?

NB:

- If I do this with ES5 syntax it works, so the server.info.uri is correct.
- I'm not getting any errors in node / nodemon

Comment: You might want to look here for further details [MDN: Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: thanks I had seen that, but after years of wrapping em in single quotes totally missed that those were backticks, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template literals are surrounded by `` ` `` (back quote) instead of `'` or `"`:

```
`Started At: ${server.info.uri}`
```